# C# connection stored procedure error

Tags: c#, mysql

This Code is establishing a Mysql Connection.

```
namespace TrialConnection
    {
        public class DataConnection
        {
            public static string database = "";
            public static string databasename = "";
            public static string user = "";
            public static string password = "";
            public static string charset = "latin1";


        string connString = "";

        public DataLayer(ref MySqlCommand newconnection)
        {
            connString = "On server = " + database + "; Databasename = " + databasename + "; User = "
                + user + "; Pass = " + password + "; Locale = " + charset; 

            newconnection = new MySqlCommand();
        }

        public bool modifyData(ref MySqlCommand newconnection, Alter_Procedures myQuery)
        {
            MySqlConnection myconnection = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            newconnection.Connection = myconnection;
            newconnection.CommandText = modifyQuery.ToString();
            newconnection.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            MySqlTransaction mytransaction = null;

            try
            {
             myconnection.Open();
     mytransaction = myconnection.BeginTransaction();
             newconnection.Transaction = mytransaction;
             newconnection.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
             mytransaction.Commit();
             mytransaction.Dispose();
             myconnection.Close();
             myconnection.Dispose();
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }

        public bool getData(ref MySqlCommand newconnection, Retrieve_Procedures allproc, ref MySqlDataReader myReader)
        {
            MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            newconnection.Connection = myConnection;
            newconnection.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            newconnection.CommandText = allproc.ToString();

            myConnection.Open();
            myReader = newconnection.ExecuteReader();
        }

    }
}
```

Whenever I try to connect and there is no stored procedure yet in the database, it is not always taking the values for my database, databasename, user, Password and charset.

I tried to debug it and found something, however I am not sure whether I found everything.

I am very thankful for help.

Comment: is there an exception thrown? if so: what *exactly* does it say? and on what line? Note that string concatenation is not a good idea here - there are escaping rules for connection strings; you might want to use `DbConnectionStringBuilder` or see if there is a `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder`

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to use DbConnectionStringBuilder here? The exception is that it is not taking my database, user, Password because it is not set.

Comment: Something like: `var builder = new DbConnectionStringBuilder(); builder["On server"] = "database"; builder["Databasename"] = "dbname"; builder["User"] = "your user"; builder["Pass"] = "password goes here"; builder["Locale"] = "latin1"; var cs = builder.ConnectionString;` (obviously change all the stuff on the right). If there is a `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` it might expose things more conveniently (`builder.Locale = "latin1";` for example) and handle any provider-specific escaping rules.